# Why is variable sized object initialization not allowed using const

Tags: c, compiler-construction, constants

This is wrong since a variable sized object may not be initialized

```
int size = 4;
int array[size] = {1};
```

`size` is a variable, but doesn't the compiler know its value when it creates `array` (Isn't `size` assigned an initial value of 4 at compile-time?)? Let `size` change after that, why would it be an issue? I mean, these are consecutive instructions, what could possibly alter the value of `size` before the array is declared?

Second question:
Why is this not allowed:

```
const int size = 4;
int array[size] = {1};
```

I am declaring `size` as a const. I know that const != read-only, and that declaring `size` as a macro is the correct way to go about it. But if I promise the compiler using const that I wont change the value of `size`, why is it not allowed?

Comment: The second version not work for u?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Its not supposed to be about VLAs because the length is always 4. The first example is just to emphasize the difference between const/non-const

Comment: @missingno I can see that, it is not really clear but I see it now.

Comment: Oh, how, wow, dupe-closed. People, this is **not** a duplicate of the proposed "duplicate".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the first question is "because the language specification says so". Although a compiler *may* be able to infer the size of the array, doing so requires some static analysis which is not trivial when the array size is not a compile-time constant expression.

As to why initialization of VLAs is not allowed: one reason ***I*** can think of is that it is not known until runtime how many elements they will contain, so a VLA may be shorter than its initializer list, which would invoke undefined behavior. I can't tell for sure if this is (one of) the real reason(s), though.

> Second question: Why is this not allowed:

It **is** allowed, unless <s>you</s> the writers of your compiler are living in a cave (for example, the engineers over at Microsoft do -- their C compiler is one rare example of a widely used compiler that **still** does not support C99, 15 years after its standardization.). Any modern, decent C compiler should enable you to use variable-length arrays which are present in C99. Compilers that already implement C11 may or may not opt to support VLAs (as it's an optional feature of the latest standard).

Comment: gcc-4.7.3 still complains about `const int size=4; int array[size] = {1};`

Comment: @KVM And? It's perfectly fine. As you observed correctly, you can't initialize a VLA.

Comment: What i mean by `why is it not allowed` was why does declaring `size` as a const _not_ allow me to initialize the array. I am curious to know the rationale behind it. If I am promising the compiler I wont alter the value of `size`, initializing the VLA should be allowed

Comment: @KVM Because a `const` is not a constexpr. Again, see #1, I answered *just that.*

Comment: `doing so requires some static analysis which is not trivial when the array size is not a compile-time constant expression` Evaluation of a const is compile time, right?

Comment: @KVM It (usually) is. Associating the value with the name is less trivial, and there may be cases when even the value of a `const` may change (for example, `volatile` qualified `const`s in an embedded system -- it's really a "variable", changeable by the hardware, but code is only allowed to read it.)

Comment: @KVM: a `const`-qualified variable is not a *constant expression* (compile-time constant) in C; it's simply a runtime variable whose value may not be modified after initialization.  A *constant expression* would be a numeric literal, a macro that expands to a numeric literal, an arithmetic expression consisting only of numeric literals or macros, or a macro that expands to such an expression, such as `#define ARR_SIZE WORDS + SPACES + 1`.