# Why am I unable to use a variable when using the map() function?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int num = 2;
    string map[num][3] = {{"c","d","s"}, {"A", "u", "p"}};
    for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                {
                    cout << map[y][x];
                }

                cout << endl;
            }
}
```

I'm using Xcode and it gives me an error saying "Variable-sized object may not be initialized". Am I simply doing it wrong or is the map function unable to take in variables as arguments?

Comment: There is no `map` function here; the code attempts to define an array whose name is `map`. The same problem would occur if the name was `foo`, `bar`, or `billy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can declare an array only with constant size, which can be deduced
> at compile time.

source: [variable-sized object may not be initialized c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751075/variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized-c/23751096)

SO, change the line:

```
unsigned int num = 2;
```

to this:

```
unsigned const num = 2;
```